# Woocommerce: remove total sum from new order's email

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

How is it possible in Woocommerce 3.2.6 to remove the total sum from new order's email for customer as well as for admin? There is now such code in email template.

```
<?php
/**
* Admin new order email
*
* This template can be overridden by copying it to 
yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php.
*
* HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and 
you
* (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
* maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it 
does
* happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped 
and
* the readme will list any important changes.
*
* @see      https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
* @author WooThemes
* @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails/HTML
* @version 2.5.0
*/

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit;
}

/**
* @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as 
follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?>
</p>

<?php

/**
* @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
* @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured 
data.
* @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured 
data.
* @since 2.5.0
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, 
$plain_text, $email );

/**
* @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, 
$plain_text, 
$email );

/**
* @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
* @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, 
$plain_text, $email );

/**
* @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find and edit new order email template and code for generating the new email in the directory "plugins\woocommerce\templates\emails\email-order-details.php".

i hope its useful and ll solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems this is the desired code: `<?php
    if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
     $i = 0;
     foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
      $i++;
      ?><tr>
       <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
       <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
      </tr><?php
     }
    }`